# Long time between submit and start time of a command in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I'm running a kernel on a big array. When I profile the clEnqueueNDRange command, the execution time (end-start) is .001 ms but the time between submit and start (start-submit) is around 120 ms which varies with the size of the input data. What happens when a command is submitted until it start to execute. Is it reasonable to get this large time?

Comment: Do you have something after your clEnqueueNDRange call that requires the result of the kernel?  For example, is there a blocking clEnqueueMapBuffer after the kernel?  If not, the implementation may be deciding to delay execution of the kernel.

Comment: Yes I do have two clEnqueueReadBuffer after that to read the result but I cannot read the result with a non blocking call. Also clEnqueueMapBuffer seems to have some problems that gives me the wrong result. Anyway is it possible to read the data with a non blocking call?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL operates asynchronously. That is to say that when you ask for a piece of work to be done, it may not happen at that time. It will happen at some time in the future. This is a little weird, especially when you start profiling things, but it works like this so that the CPU can queue up lots of work for the OpenGL device, and then go do something else while the work is done.

For example:

```
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(blah);
clEnqueueNDRange(blah);
clEnqueueReadBuffer(blah, but blocking_read = CL_TRUE);
```

Here, the writeBuffer and the NDRange will probably appear to take very small amounts of time. All they'll do is record what needs to be done. The blocking readBuffer will take a long time, because it has to wait for the results of the read. For that read to complete, the write, and the kernel execution have to complete, before the read can even start.

Now the read might be very small, but because it's waiting for everything before it to finish the time it appears to take is dependent on the amount of work in the commands before it.

I don't quite understand what you're measuring from your question, but I expect what you're seeing is this effect. The time for work is being charged to other functions because they have to wait for previous work to finish.

Knowing which functions cause the CPU to wait on the GPU is one of the big tricks when it comes to writing high performance code. Any time you introduce a wait like this the CPU stops doing any useful work, and the GPU is likely to go idle whilst the CPU prepares the next lump of work. Sometimes, there no alternative, and you just have to wait.